# Most elegant/simple proof of the irrationality of $\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pi

What is the most elegant/shortest proof of this? The proofs I have seen are quite long, unlike the proof of the irrationality of $e$.

thanks

Comment: This would help: http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.bams/1183510788

Comment: I think pretty much all of the proofs require some basic calculus.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational#Niven.27s_proof I've always found Niven's proof the simplest.

Comment: You won't find one as short as the proof for $e$. The series for $e$ makes it easy.

Comment: $$\begin{array}{rll}&1.&\text{Suppose that }\pi\in\Bbb Q.&\\&2.&\text{This contradicts all those long proofs that state otherwise.}&\\&&&\implies\pi\notin\Bbb Q.\ \square\end{array}$$ (With regards to Zach Weinersmith of SMBC.)

Comment: FWIW: http://www.cross-reference-kingdom.com/temo-irrationality-of-pi.html

Answer (score 2):

Niven's proof. See the comments for a link.

Answer (score 0):

Although the first proof of irrationality of $\pi$ dates back to 1760s, the simplest proof known today was discovered surprisingly recently (Zhou & Markov, 2010): the toolbox provides only integration by parts and familiarity with sequences and limits. It is a pity that this proof is not popular (for example I can't find it in S.E.). I'll write it here to share this interesting result.

1. Lets define
   \begin{equation}
   P_n (x) = \frac{(x(\pi - x))^n}{n!} \tag{1a}
   \end{equation}
   \begin{equation}
   I_n = \int_0^\pi P_n (x) \sin x dx \tag{1b}
   \end{equation}
   where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
2. Exploiting integration by parts $\int udv = uv - \int v du$ I put $u=P_n(x)$ and $dv = \sin x dx$ finding (please note that $P_n(0) = P_n (\pi)=0$)
   \begin{equation}
    I_n = \int_0^\pi P'_n (x) \cos x dx \tag{2}
   \end{equation}
   Putting then $u=P_n' (x)$ and $dv = \cos x dx$ we find ($\sin x$ is zero in extremes)
   \begin{equation}
   I_n = - \int_0^\pi P_n'' (x) \sin x dx \tag{3}
   \end{equation}
3. It is easy to check next identity ($P_n(x)$ is defined for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ so the presence of $P_{n-1}$ implies $n\in \mathbb{N}^+$)
   \begin{equation}
    P_n' (x) = P_{n-1} (x) (\pi - 2x) \quad (n \ge 1) \tag{4}
   \end{equation}
   By deriving and exploiting $P_{n-1}'(x)=P_{n-2}(x)(\pi-2x)$ that we can find by (4) itself, we can write
   \begin{equation}
   P_n'' (x) = P_{n-2} (x) (\pi - 2x)^2 - 2 P_{n-1} (x) \quad (n \ge 2) \tag{5}
   \end{equation}
   that we can write in this way
   \begin{equation}
    P_n'' (x) = \pi^2 P_{n-2} (x) + P_{n-2} (x) (-4\pi x + 4 x^2) - 2 P_{n-1} (x) \quad (n \ge 2) \tag{6}
   \end{equation}
   It is easy to check that the central term in the right can be written as $-4 \frac{(x(\pi-x))^{n-1}}{(n-2)!}$ ad so as $-4 P_{n-1} (x) (n-1)$. So we conclude that
   \begin{equation}
    P_n'' (x) = \pi^2 P_{n-2} (x) - (4n - 2) P_{n-1} (x) \quad (n \ge 2) \tag{7}
   \end{equation}
4. Exploiting (7) we come back to (3) and we write
   \begin{equation}
    I_n = - \pi^2 \int_0^\pi P_{n-2} (x) \sin x dx + (4n-2) \int_0^\pi P_{n-1} (x) \sin x dx \quad (n \ge 2) \tag{8}
   \end{equation}
   Comparing with (1b) we see that
   \begin{equation}
    I_n = - \pi^2 I_{n-2} + (4n-2) I_{n-1} \quad (n \ge 2) \tag{9}
   \end{equation}
5. Seeing (1b) we immediately see that $I_0 = 2$. Also, the primitive of $x(\pi-x) \sin x$ is
   $\left( \pi -2 x\right) \sin x+ ( {x^2}-\pi x- 2) \cos x + c$, so we have $I_1 = 4$. Then, seeing that (9) allow us to find $I_n$ knowing $I_{n-1}$ and $I_{n-2}$, we see that we found a shortcut to find the seemingly complicated sequence defined in (1b): we can go on recursively and write
   \begin{equation}
    I_0 =2, \,\, I_1=4, \,\, I_2 = -2\pi^2 + 24, I_3=-24\pi^2+240, \textrm{ ecc.} \tag{10}
   \end{equation}
6. Now observe that if $Q_{n-2} (x)$ and $Q_{n-1} (x)$ are polynomials with integer coefficients,
   \begin{equation}
    Q_n (x) = - x Q_{n-2} (x) + (4n-2) Q_{n-1} (x) \tag{11}
   \end{equation}
   too is a polynomial with integer coefficients: (11) defines an infinite sequence of polynomials with integer coefficients that depend on $n$. By comparing with (9) and and step 5 we see that if we use as starting polynomial (to define recursively the sequence) the polynomials $Q_0=2$ and $Q_1 = 4$, then all polynomials of the sequence (11) assume in $\pi^2$ the value $I_n$. This happens because if $x=\pi^2$ and if the first and the second term of the sequence are the same, (9) and (11) *are* the same sequence. In other words, the sequence of polynomial satisfy the following equation
   \begin{equation}
   Q_n (\pi^2) = I_n \quad (n \ge 2) \tag{12}
   \end{equation}
   Please note that it is a perfectly legal recursive definition: the infinite sequence of polynomials with this property is well defined by (11) and by the choice of the first two polynomials. For example we can write these first terms of the sequence: $Q_0=2$, $Q_1=4$, $Q_2=-2x+24$, $Q_3(x)=-24x+240$, $Q_4(x)=2x^2-360x+3360$, ecc.
7. At this point we assume by contradiction that
   \begin{equation}
    \pi^2 = \frac{a}{b} \tag{13}
   \end{equation}
   with $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$. By multiplying both sides of (12) by $b^n$ we can write
   \begin{equation}
    b^n I_n = b^n Q_n (\pi^2) \quad (n \ge 2) \tag{14}
   \end{equation}
   But the $n^\textrm{th}$ term of the polynomial sequence given by (11) and starting polynomial $Q_0=2$ and $Q_1 = 4$ can't have degree greater that $n$ (the first two term have zero degree and $n+1$ term can at most increase degree by 1: in (11) there is a multiplication by $x$). So $Q_n (\pi^2)$ as polynomial with integer coefficients with argument, $\frac{a}{b}$, has denominators multiple of $b$, ad all lower than $b^n$. In other words $b^n Q_n (\pi^2)$ is integer, and from (14) we conclude that
   \begin{equation}
    b^n I_n \in \mathbb{N} \quad (n \ge 2) \tag{15}
   \end{equation}
8. Now we observe that $I_n$ given by (1b) must be lower of the integral of the constant function in which $P_n(x)$ and $\sin x$ have the maximum possible value. Deriving $P_n(x)$ we see that if $x \in (0,\pi)$ (we are interested to this interval, looking to the extreme of integration) we have a maximum in $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$, where $P_n(x)$ has value $\frac{\left( \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \right)^n}{n!}$. So it must be true the following inequality
   \begin{equation}
    I_n < \int_0^\pi \frac{\left( \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \right)^n}{n!}dx \quad (n \ge 2) \tag{16}
   \end{equation}
   By multiplying both sides by $b^n$ and integrating the constant function, we get
   \begin{equation}
    b^n I_n < \frac{\left( \frac{b \pi^2}{4} \right)^n}{n!} \pi \quad (n \ge 2) \tag{17}
   \end{equation}
9. For any finite $b$, the sequence on the right in (17) goes to zero if $n \to \infty$. The left side is smaller so it too goes to zero. But (15) must be true for any $n$, big $n$ too, so we get a contradiction: a quantity cannot be integer for any $n$ if it can be smaller and smaller near zero taking $n$ big. Conclusion: the hypothesis (13) that lead us to (15) and (17) cannot be true: $\pi^2$ is irrational.
10. Finally, let's suppose that $\pi$ is the rational number $\frac{p}{q}$. If this were the case, $\pi^2$ too (i.e. $\frac{p^2}{q^2}$) would be rational. But we have shown that $\pi^2$ is irrational, so $\pi$ too must be irrational.

Finally, two thoughts of mine

- First of all, please note that reflecting on step 10 we can conclude that we proof something more than the irrationality of $\pi$. If a number is irrational, any its $n^{\textrm{th}}$ must be irrational, so from irrationality of $\pi^2$ we can deduce the irrationality of all infinite terms of the sequence
  $\{ \pi^\frac{2}{n} , n \in \mathbb{N}^+ \}$. So are irrational this numbers
  \begin{equation}
  \sqrt{\pi}, \sqrt[3]{\pi} , \sqrt[4]{\pi} , \sqrt[5]{\pi}, \dots \tag{18}
  \end{equation}
  and this numbers too
  \begin{equation}
   \sqrt[3]{\pi^2}, \sqrt[5]{\pi^2}, \sqrt[7]{\pi^2}, \dots \tag{19}
  \end{equation}
  But this proof say nothing about the rationality of many other interesting numbers, as
  \begin{equation}
  \pi^3, \sqrt{\pi^3}, \pi^4, \pi^\pi, \pi^e, \pi^{\sqrt{2}}, \textrm{ ecc} \tag{20}
  \end{equation}
- A final comment. We didin't proof it, but this result too is valid:
  $$
  \nexists k \in \mathbb{Q}^* : \pi^k \textrm{ is rational}
  $$
  Indeed, for a such $k$ we would have $\pi=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}$ and so $\pi$ would be solution of $b x^k - a = 0$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$; but this is impossible because in 1882 Lindemann proved that $\pi$ is transcendental. This ensures that first three terms in (20) are irrational. As for the other three terms, nobody knows today if they are rational or irrational (by the way, we *know* that $e^\pi$ is irrational, and transcendental too, as showed by Gelfond in 1934), and there is the possibility that human mind will never be so powerful to know the true about that beautiful enigmas that nature offers us. A true must exists, and some way to reach it too, but we cannot exclude that these ways are too difficult for human beings. As said by many scientists in the past, we can with joy seeing some fragments of beauty on the beach, but ocean unknown stretches out in front of us.

Comment: Describing the proof with 10 steps having a lot of technical details shown can make it look overly complicated, rather than being in the spirit of being "the simplest known proof".  To streamline the discussion, you could combine steps 1 to 4 into a single step: using integration by parts twice, you get (9). See the bottom of page 3 and top of page 4 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/irrational.pdf.

Comment: In my opinion, breaking up the proof into well-defined separate parts is the best way to make it more readable, and this seems to me to be generally considered true otherwise we would not use lemmas in mathematics textbooks.  As for explaining every detail at length, perhaps for someone I am excessively verbose, but my aim is always the same: to simplify life for the reader as much as possible. Perhaps whether or not my style is appreciated depends on the preparation of the reader. You find I dwell but another reader might appreciate that all the steps are explicitly explained in detail.